# Mouse Events on Application Window

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

I've an eclipse e4 application. I'm trying to run some code say `xyz()` when the window is resized. The issue is that while resizing the resize listener is called multiple times and I want to call `xyz()` only once after the user has done resizing. The only way that I can think is to capture the mouseUp event on the window itself, but couldn't figure an API to get the same.

Sample code

```
public class CTGHandler{
    @Execute
    public void execute(final EPartService partService, final EModelService modelService){
        MPart mPart = modelService.createModelElement(MPart.class);
        mPart.setLabel("CTGLive"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        mPart.setContributionURI("bundleclass://test.ui.ctg/test.ui.ctg.CTGPart"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        partService.showPart(mPart, PartState.ACTIVATE);
    }
}

public class CTGPart    {
    @Inject
    private IEventBroker eventBroker;

    @Inject
    public CTGPart(){
        //Do something here...
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(final Composite parent){
        Composite grandParent = parent.getParent().getParent().getParent();
        System.out.println(grandParent); //Prints "Shell {CTGApp}"

        grandParent.addControlListener(new ControlListener() {              
            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e){
                System.out.println(e); // Prints "ControlEvent{Shell {CTGApp} time=9286942 data=null}" multiple times for a single resize event
                // because there is no way the framework can understand if the resize was complete
                xyz();// called each time, but I want this to be called only once 
            }

            @Override
            public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e)
            {}
        });
        // MouseUp event on the application window so that xyz(); can be called once and we can get rid of grandParent.addControlListener(){...}
    }

}
```

Comment: A window can be resized without dragging with the mouse.

Comment: What it is you actually want to do when the resize is done? There might be another approach.

Comment: This is exactly what [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) is for: using the `throttleWithTimeout` function you can be triggered on an event, but wait until the events stop firing in quick succession before you actually act - the boilerplate code would be about 7 lines for an RxSwing equivalent `fromResizing` call. There is no implementation library that I know of for e4, but you could quickly rustle up a single class using the RxSwing `ComponentEventSource` and `SwingObservable` as a template.

Comment: @greg-449 In my case the resize is via the mouse. On the final resize I want to make a database call to fetch some data.

Comment: @AndyBrown e4 uses SWT, Swing code is not useful

Comment: @greg-449. that's exactly what I just said: use RxSwing as a template for dealing with UI events and build your own `fromResizeable` for SWT and e4. From taking a quick look I don't think it would need much effort. You just need to swap the listeners, use the ControlEvent to get at the data and alter the threading model a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it better to defer the processing of the resize event using a [ScheduledFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) and a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

If you keep a reference to the Future you can cancel the previous one and schedule a new one. This way you can collapse many events triggered in a short time period into a single slightly delayed event. You need to pick a good delay time to balance the number of events that will be swallowed against the delay that will occur after the last future has been scheduled.

```
grandParent.addControlListener(new ControlListener() { 
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;
    @Override
    public void controlResized(ControlEvent e){
        if(scheduledFuture != null) {
            scheduledFuture.cancel();
        }
        scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                xyz();
                return null;
            }
            }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e)
    {}
});
```

If you get a lot of events you should create a static Callable rather than create a new one each time.

Comment: Malcolm I tried your approach and it works well in most cases. The key as you mentioned is to pick a good delay. I will try @andy-brown 's approach as well

Comment: As far as I understand, RxJava is basically doing the same thing but you will also be pulling in a sophisticated "library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences". This might be appropriate if it helps solves other issues in your app, but if not going with a simple core API solution is probably simpler.

Comment: @SDS. I totally agree with Malcolm: futures are the simplest solution for this problem. RxJava is very powerful but, while it brings a whole load of benefits with it, there is no implementation for SWT. That means some up-front work before you can start using buffering, windowing, throttling with the UI events ... too long for an SO answer.

Comment: Futures just does what I need, so sticking with it.